# how to persist data in IsolatedStorageSettings in windows phone even when application is closed?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I want to store some basic information to prevent login each time for that I am using IsolatedStorageSettings but data is stored only till application is open how can I persist data even when application is closed and get back when application is started again. My code is as below to store information I uses

```
public static IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
settings.Add("user", MainPage.user);
```

to retrive it I use

```
if (MainPage.settings.Contains("user"))
{
      MainPage.user = (User)MainPage.settings["user"];                            
}
```

here MainPage.user is a static object of class User in class MainPage.

Comment: do you use real device or emulator?

Comment: Do you use JSON data? If yes, do you deserialize it properly before saving?

Comment: Yes I have used json and I can serialize and deserialize it! so now I have no need to use DataContractAttribute and settings.save() works!
Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the [`Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method:

```
settings.Save();
```

Comment: I am getting this error in using settings.save() 
Type 'vUrja_Mobile_Json.Device' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.

Comment: @Kevan: here is an article that explains what you want to do in details: http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/windows-phone-how-easily-store

Comment: This is also usefull Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have two assumptions here:

1) You don't call settings.Save() method

2) You're working on emulator and close it, that'll cause all your settings to die.

Your user class should look like this:

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class User
    {
        [DataMemberAttribute]
        private String field;

        public String _Field
        {
            get { return field; }
            set { field = value; }
        }
    }
```

just set [DataMemberAttribute] for every field you want to save.

Comment: If you can't save a class, than you should mark the class with [DataContractAttribute] or [DataContract] and the fields, you want to save with [DataMemberAttribute] or [DataMember].

Comment: I am to closing emulator each time 
I am getting this error in using settings.save() Type 'vUrja_Mobile_Json.Device' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.

Comment: can you please tell me in which assembly this attribute is given because I am getting this error.

The type or namespace name 'DataContractAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: System.Runtime.Serialization

Comment: btw, writing *DataContractAttribute* in Google would give you the right assembly much quicker.

Comment: Thanks Olter for you quick responce. I googled it first and also got this ans  System.Runtime.Serialization but practically it was not working and still I was getting same error thats why I has pasted  that here.

Comment: Arrrgh, alright. Post your User class code, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to Add Settings:

```
private IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
appSettings.Add("user", "SOME_STRING_DATA");
```

To Update Settings:

```
private IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
appSettings["user"] = "some_string_content";
```

To Retrieve Settings:

```
private IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
string value = (string)appSettings["user"];
```

This works without using Save() function.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: That looks like almost the same code as OP has written. Can't see any difference.

Comment: He has mentioned using `settings.Save();` and I have no where mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

IsolatedStorageSettings stores data in a 'key value' pair and to save it use IsolatedStorageSettings.Save() Method:

```
var lastOpenedFileSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
  if (!lastOpenedFileSettings.Contains("yourSeetingKey"))
       {
         lastOpenedFileSettings.Add("yourSeetingKey", yourSettingValue);
        }
   IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

To retrive setting value cast it into required datatype:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings lastOpenedFileSettings =IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
 string lastOpenedFileId = (string)lastOpenedFileSettings["yourSeetingKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like every thing OK in your code expect below line of code. Remove static when you define IsolatedStorageSettings object. your code should be...

```
public IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

and make following changes in your app.xaml.cs file

```
 private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
        {
           // SettingView.LiveClient = null;
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
        }

        // Code to execute when the application is closing (eg, user hit Back)
        // This code will not execute when the application is deactivated
        private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
        }
```